# IEnumerable Extension Method Doesn't Appear for Lists

Tags: c#, extension-methods, ienumerable

I'm trying to create just a generic extension method for IEnumerables where I can randomize the contents inside of them. I was writing my tests, and found that while it works just fine for Arrays, Lists did not have the extended methods available as an option. I'm curious if there is a mis-understanding on my end of the implementation of the interface for List or something I'm missing. An explanation or what I'm doing incorrectly would be greatly appreciated.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Randomizes the order of an array.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of object this holds.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="list">The enumerable that is being modified.</param>
    /// <returns>The randomized enumerable.</returns>
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetRandomList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        return GenerateRandomEnumerable<T>(list);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Randomizes the order of an array.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of array this is.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="list">The array that is being modified.</param>
    public static void RandomizeOrder<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        IEnumerable<T> newList = GenerateRandomEnumerable<T>(list);

        // Reassign the values
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count(); i++)
        {
            T item = list.ElementAt(i);
            item = newList.ElementAt(i);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Randomizes the order of an enumerable.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of object this holds.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="list">The enumerable that is being modified.</param>
    /// <returns>A randomized enumerable.</returns>
    private static IEnumerable<T> GenerateRandomEnumerable<T>(IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        // Create the list and randomizer that will be needed
        List<KeyValuePair<int, T>> returnList = new List<KeyValuePair<int, T>>();
        Random randomizer = new Random();

        // Move the enumerable into a new list with random numbers
        foreach (T curT in list)
        {
            returnList.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, T>(randomizer.Next(), curT));
        }

        // Sort by the random value
        returnList.Sort((a, b) => a.Key.CompareTo(b.Key));

        // Return the randomized enumerable
        return returnList.Select(x => x.Value);
    }
```

**EDIT**

I am trying to hopefully convey the issue, but I'll try and clarify more.

If I write this:

```
int[] testArray = new int[3]{1,2,3};
testArray.RandomizeOrder<int>();
```

That works perfectly fine.

However, when I try to write this:

```
List<int> originalList = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
originalList.RandomizeOrder<int>();
```

It says that List does not contain a member RandomizeOrder and the best extension method overload RandomizeOrder(this int[]) has some invalid arguments. So these are the lines that are currently causing me problems. This is in the same class as the functioning code so the namespaces are all there, it is only the list here that is causing me a problem.

Probably something very simple and stupid that I'm overlooking, but assistance would be helpful. Thank you in advance.

**P.S.**
I also am not sure if this matters, this project is also in .NET 2.0, if that effects this. Sorry I didn't mention before.

Comment: The syntax looks ok, assuming that this is within a static class. Did you include the correct namespaces in your tests?

Comment: Add code that you have written for testing purpose and did not work. It will help people to provide better solution.

Comment: Yes. All of this is indeed a static class. It works fine as long as the object that I'm trying to modify is an array. So int [] works great. But if I try List <int> then these methods are not available to me. I was under the impression that List <T> implemented IEnumerable which is why I'm confused.

Comment: Reiterating your question in the comments won't help. What _will_ help is showing a _complete_ code example that demonstrates the problem. `List<T>` does in fact implement `IEnumerable<T>` so your extension methods (note that only the first two are extension methods...you don't have `this` in the parameter list of the third method) would work. Since they don't, you have done something else wrong, in the code you didn't share with us.

Comment: @Repareman It worked for me just fine look at here https://dotnetfiddle.net/CRFwue

Comment: .Net 2.0 does not have extension methods. Are you sure you are using this framework version?

Comment: I really really apologize to everyone. Another team member had modified the namespace of this specific class, but left an old version that just had the array covered in the project and I did not realize it. Please do not spend more time on this. I really am sorry for this, I'll try and be more thorough in the future before coming here. My apologies.